# JAVA Reporting Tool iReport

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports, ireport

Can we get a reporting page which is like .Net's Crystal report using iReport? That is I need to get the report inside the frame.

Comment: clarify exactly what are you trying to achieve. So that people who haven't used crystal report can answer.

Comment: Without open report in a new window, I want to assign it like a panel.

Comment: i used crystal reports, and im still not sure what you want!

Comment: The following code will open a new Report window,

JasperDesign jd = JRXMLoader.load(“FilePath”);
JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr),null,con);
JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);

How can i get that report page inside the Frame.

Comment: By the sounds of things you are trying to load your report using JasperViewer but instead opening a new window you want to load it within an already open panel?

Comment: Yes you are right I am asking that only. Help me.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using Swing, here is an example how to do it.

**Edit:**

Try getting the JasperViewer container and add that to the main JFrame or JPanel.

Bit of a hack job but it should do the trick.

```
JasperDesign jd = JRXMLoader.load("FilePath"); 
JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport((jr),null,con);
// Create an instance of the JasperViewer instead of using the static call
JasperViewer viewer=new JasperViewer(jp,false);
// Get the viewers container and add that to the main frame or panel
Container container = viewer.getContentPane();
myMainJFrame.add(container);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply your code is right. But while adding this code i got the error 

"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container"


This code works properly JFrame j = viewer;

But it opens a new JFrame window. Is there any possible option to add that in panel. Thanks in advance.